# unterminated string literal in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one string in my JSON. the value is `To be Reviewed`.

I am retrieving this string in my client side using `data[i].status` syntax. It fetches the correct value but when I send this syntax as paramter it gives `unterminated string literal` error on client side.

My code is:

```
onClick=test('"+data[i].product+"','"+data[i].status+"').
```

How can I send the string value in another function?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are appending variables you do not need the quotes around them, only the value you are assigning to the `onClick` parameter. Assuming your `test` function accepts two parameters, this should work:

```
onClick="test(data[i].product, data[i].status)"
```